# Spring Boot connection to SQL Server in Windows Authentication mode

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, salesforce

I am trying to connect to SQL Server in Windows Authentication mode and here is my database configuration:

```
database.name= DatabaseName spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://1.2.3.4:11111;DatabaseName=${database.name};integratedSecurity = true;
 spring.datasource.username=user
 spring.datasource.password=passw
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

and I got these errors:

*Negative matches:*

---

```
AVSSimulatorServerApplication:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.application.name=avs-simulator-service) found different value in property 'spring.application.name' (OnPropertyCondition)

ActiveMQAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory', 'org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false) found different value in property 'proxy-target-class' (OnPropertyCondition)

   ArtemisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory', 'org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   AsyncCustomAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.sleuth.async.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
.......

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'user'. ClientConnectionId:ce912574-1f20-4843-9b43-01820e67cf54

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'user'. ClientConnectionId:ce912574-1f20-4843-9b43-01820e67cf54

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.HashMap]: 

................
```

Does anybody know what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it was only to use

```
integratedSecurity = false;
```

instead of

```
integratedSecurity = true;
```

so in this case connection string will be:

```
database.name= DatabaseName spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://1.2.3.4:11111;DatabaseName=${database.name};**integratedSecurity = false**;.
```

Why to use `integratedSecurity = false`?
The reason is here:

> *Integrated Security When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).